# R: Understanding the ggnetwork package and its usage with ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, igraph, ggnetwork

I am learning to plot network graph using ggplot2, igraph and ggnetwork. I am studying this webpage:

https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggnetwork/vignettes/ggnetwork.html#geom_edges

However, I have some very basic questions in order to understand how the functions work. In the example under the heading 'geom_edges', the code is

```
ggplot(n, aes(x = x, y = y, xend = xend, yend = yend)) 
    + geom_edges(aes(linetype = type), color = "grey50") 
    + theme_blank()
```

I do not understand

- how does it actually use the ggnetwork package in the statement. Is it implicitly? How?
- what does `x = x, y = y, xend = xend, yend = yend` mean? What are x, y, xend and yend?
- how do the parameters x, y, xend, yend relate to the data object n?

Many thanks!

Comment: `geom_edges` is a function exported from the `ggnetwork` package, so if you didn't have that package loaded, the code wouldn't work. The `x` and `y` parameters inside `aes` map two of your variables to the x and y co-ordinates of your plot. Since edges need a start and an end co-ordinate, you also need `xend` and `yend` to specify these. Since you are likely to have lots of edges in a plot, these parameters are all vectorized, so you can pass 4 columns from the data frame `n` to map to `x`, `y`, `xend` and `yend`, so each row in your data frame can give one edge on the plot.

Comment: Hi. Seems you are looking for an intro to `ggplot2`. There are a few tutorial listed under the `ggplot2` tag: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/ggplot2/info The package `ggnetwork` adds `geom_edges` here.

Answer (score 0):

As previous commenters have said, the `x`, `xend`, `y` and `yend` parameters in the example code, which are used to plot nodes and edges between them, work exactly like in [`geom_segment`](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/geom_segment.html). The `ggnetwork` builds on `ggplot2`, so some knowledge of that package is required to work with it.

What the package brings on top of `ggplot2` are functions like `geom_edges`: see [its documentation](https://briatte.github.io/ggnetwork/reference/index.html) for the full list of functions.